# How to change an element using a select dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change an element through a select drop down menu- however, I'm unable to get it to change dynamically.

```
<select id="optMapList">
        <option>Map 1</option>
        <option>Map 2</option>
</select>
<script>
document.getElementById("maptype").innerHTML=optMapList.options[optMapList.selectedIndex].text
</script>
```

Comment: That is not Java as you have in the tags but Javascript please change it as there is a big difference despite the name.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to run fine. I think you're missing the fact that you have to listen to a 'change'-event in order to by able to run code on changes. This is done as follows:

```
var optMapList = document.getElementById('optMapList');

optMapList.onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById("maptype").innerHTML = optMapList.options[optMapList.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/thijs_s/gx9mf1ct/

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make it so the first option is a default upon loading?

Comment: Sure, you just need to call the `onchange()`-function. So you add 1 line: `optMapList.onchange();` (example: http://jsfiddle.net/thijs_s/gx9mf1ct/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the value property of the select list inside an event listener as noted below.

```
var optMapList = document.getElementById('optMapList');

optMapList.onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("maptype").innerHTML = optMapList.value;}
```